# How to get the current remote webdriver instance inside onTestFailure(ITestResult)

Tags: screenshot, testng, remotewebdriver

I want to integrate the code to take screenshot using remoteWebdriver inside, testng's `onTestFailure(ITestResult)`. I am unable to get the current webdriver instance inside `onTestFailure()`.

Comment: This would depend on how are you instantiating your driver.  Can you share the code which does the instantiation?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, driver was initialized by a base class. I solved the problem by using ((BaseClass) currentInstance).getBrowser();

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had a similar problem.
And since there's no clear answer here, I would post my ( working) solution

On your BaseTest / TestBase class, make your RemoteWebdriver instance accessible ( either by having it as a public property or with a getter)

In the Listener class (In my case its a public property):

```
public class BaseTest {
    public RemoteWebDriver remoteDriver;
    //... initalize driver
}

public class TestListener implements ITestListener {
@Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        BaseTest test = (BaseTest) result.getInstance();
        if (test == null) {
            return;
        }
        RemoteWebDriver driver = test.remoteDriver;
    }
}
```